# ASP.NET MVC3 Template. Trying to split data into three columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, for-loop

I think this is a really simple questions, but I'm new to ASP.NET MVC.

I retrieve the data from the model, but I want to split it up into three columns of equal length, or as close to equal length as possible.

These for-loops aren't doing the trick, so I'm a little bit lost as to how to best do this in the template.

Thanks.

[image]

EDIT: I solved it in a much better way. It can be done in css like this:

```
    <div class="topic_content">
        <div>
        <ul>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Topics.Length; i++)
            {
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="company_topic" data-popularity="@Model.Topics[i].Popularity" data-topicId="@Model.Topics[i].Id">@Model.Topics[i].Name.ToLower()</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

And then in CSS I set:

```
.topic_content ul { width: 100%; }
.topic_content ul li { list-style: none; text-align: left; float:left; width:33%; }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it always be `i < Model.Topics.Length * (1/3)`? If there are none left to output, then break out of the loop.

Comment: Just so you know, Model.Topics.Length * (1/3) would always evaluate to 0. (1/3) is using integer division. 1/3 will always evaluate to 0 and Model.Topics.Length * 0 is of course also 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article of CSS techniques to get it done.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in C#, here's how I would recommend doing it:

```
@{
    var topics = Model.Topics;
    var takeCount = Model.Topics.Count() / 3;
}
@for( i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
    <div class="topic_content">
        <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach( var topic in topics.Take( takeCount ) )
            {
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="company_topic" data-popularity="@topic.Popularity" data-topicId="@topic.Id">@topic.Name.ToLower()</a></li>
            }
            @{ topics = topics.Skip( takeCount ); }
        </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you WolfyUK.  What didn't work?  I have used this exact solution many times, and I'm curious how it didn't work for you?

Comment: The logic seemed incorrect as I only got two instead of three columns. The other solution I've linked to worked fine though.

Comment: Hm.  I'd have to see your implementation to know what went wrong.  The logic is solid.  Regardless, glad the other solution worked for you.